# How to convert d3.value() iterable and d3.rollup from javaScript into TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to convert [this horizontal stacked bar chart code](https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-horizontal-bar-chart) from plain javaScript into my typeScript Angular app.

When I get to this part of the code:

```
const series = d3
      .stack()
      .keys(zDomain)
      .value(([, I], z: any) => {
        return X[I.get(z)];
      })
      .order(order)
      .offset(offset)(
        d3.rollup(
          I,
          ([i]) => i,
          (i) => Y[i],
          (i) => Z[i]
        )
      )
      .map((s) => s.map((d) => Object.assign(d, { i: d.data[1].get(s.key) })));
```

I get the following compilation errors:

> ERROR in app/d3.service.ts:171:15 - error TS2488: Type '{ [key:
> string]: number; }' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that
> returns an iterator.
>
> 171       .value(([, I], z: any) => {
> ~~~~~ app/d3.service.ts:176:9 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'InternMap<any, InternMap<{}, number>>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<{ [key: string]: number;
> }>'.                               Types of property
> '[Symbol.iterator]' are incompatible.
> Type '() => IterableIterator<[any, InternMap<{}, number>]>' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<{ [key: string]: number; }>'.
> Type 'IterableIterator<[any, InternMap<{}, number>]>' is not assignable to type 'Iterator<{ [key: string]: number; }>'.
> Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
> Type '(value?: any) => IteratorResult<[any, InternMap<{}, number>]>' is not assignable to type '(value?: any) =>
> IteratorResult<{ [key: string]: number; }>'.
>
> ```
>         Type 'IteratorResult<[any, InternMap<{}, number>]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<{ [key: string]: number; }>'.
>           Type '[any, InternMap<{}, number>]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: number; }'.
>             Index signature is missing in type '[any, InternMap<{}, number>]'.
> ```
>
> 176         d3.rollup(
> ~~~~~~~~~~ 177           I,
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ... 180           (i) => Z[i]
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 181         )
> ~~~~~~~~~

I don't understand typeScript nor these errors well enough to understand how to typeScriptify this section of the code. Can anyone help or at least give me advice?

I have set up a minimal example of my code on StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8weygs?file=index.ts), but the compilation errors don't get reproduced there.

Update 11 March, 2022:
Here are the versions of d3 and the d3 types that I have installed:

```
"@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
"d3": "^7.1.0",
```

And here is how I import d3 in the typescript file:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Here is a photo of all of the type errors upon compile:

[image]

Comment: That's not what the community considers a *minimal* demo... You should really put in the effort to boil it down to the bare minimum required to reproduce the error. The sheer amount of code scattered across various files will discourage people—including myself—from having a closer look at the problem. No Angular, no lodash, no polyfills, get rid of all that! I bet no more than 10 lines of code in a single file will be enough to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback. Here is my dilemma: people have historically not been receptive when I have shared a github repository as a minimal demo. I also understand objections to providing only code via the SO question. Thus I have resorted to StackBlitz. There are clearly some differences between StackBlitz and local dev environments such that I can't tease out what I need to exclude. E.g., "Is it an Angular problem? I don't know because I don't get the same TypeScript linting errors on StackBlitz that I do locally". I am receptive to recommendations of how to resolve this dilemma.

Comment: @Atticus29 Can I just ask... What is the purpose of converting it to Typescript ? What you could do instead is include the [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3) for D3 and then just `import * as d3 from 'd3.js'` where `d3` is the types from `@types`

Comment: @altocumulus I've updated the example. No Angular. No lodash.  Just the function and the test data. Not the same errors though. Note the the "get" error doesn't seem to be because lodash is missing; those get calls are in the function code form observablehq.

Comment: @Zze great question. I actually DO do just that. But I'm still getting some type errors even with that!

Comment: @Zze if you can provide an example where that works, that would answer my question for sure.

Comment: @Atticus29 sorry..... Are you saying that the d3 types load correctly and that the only error you get is the one you posted? or are you saying that the d3 types are not loading correctly and there are heaps of errors?

Comment: @Zze, it seems like the second case to me. I updated the question with d3 and d3 types from my package.json, as well as a screenshot of all of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the issue here is that there is a mismatch between the `@types/d3` and the `d3` versions. I also moved the @types/d3 reference to `devDependencies` where it belongs.

This works for me on a new angular "ng new" app:

```
{
  "name": "d3-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "d3": "7.1.0", // <!-------------- explicit 7.1.0 version
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "7.1.0", // <!-------------- explicit 7.1.0 version
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

...and then as before, continue to use `import * as d3 from 'd3';`

*Note that this doesn't seem to work when I make a new `Stackblitz` - not sure why.* But here is a screenshot with the correct d3 intellisense:

[image]